# XSLT Processing two input files into one output file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to process to `xml` files (`docbook` documents). There are repeating structures in the document that I would extract from both documents, parameterize, and store in a separate document.

To get it simplified, here is an example:

`file1.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input>
    <structure>foo</structure>
    <structure>bar</structure>
    <structure>baz</structure>
</input>
```

`file2.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input>
    <structure>abc</structure>
    <structure>xyz</structure>
    <structure>123</structure>
</input>
```

And this is the preferred output, I would like to generate.
`output.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
    <structure origin="doc1">foo</structure>
    <structure origin="doc1">bar</structure>
    <structure origin="doc1">baz</structure>
    <structure origin="doc2">abc</structure>
    <structure origin="doc2">xyz</structure>
    <structure origin="doc2">123</structure>
</output>
```

Now I don't know how to convert two or more documents (URI can be hard coded) and one additional parameter (doc1, doc2 - these can also be hard coded) in XSLT.

I would be very grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you transform `file1.xml` and only read `file2.xml` with [`fn:doc()`](http://w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-doc), or set both parameters and read both is a matter of choice, but the concept applies either way. Once you have both docs loaded, you can XPath to the `/input/structure` and then apply-templates.

With XSLT 2.0, you can obtain the `base-uri()` and parse that for the filename to use in the `@origin`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="fn">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    
    <xsl:param name="file1" select="'file1.xml'" />
    <xsl:param name="file2" select="'file2.xml'" />
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="(fn:doc($file1) | fn:doc($file2))/input/structure"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="structure">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="origin" select="concat('doc', replace(base-uri(), '.*(\d+).xml', '$1'))"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you need XSLT 1.0, you could send the filename as a param:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="fn">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    
    <xsl:param name="file1" select="'file1.xml'" />
    <xsl:param name="file2" select="'file2.xml'" />
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:call-template name="load-file">
                <xsl:with-param name="file" select="$file1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:call-template name="load-file">
                <xsl:with-param name="file" select="$file2"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="load-file">
        <xsl:param name="file"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="doc($file)/input/structure">
            <xsl:with-param name="file" select="$file"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="structure">
        <xsl:param name="file"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="origin">
              <xsl:value-of select="concat('doc', substring-after(substring-before($file, '.xml'), 'file'))"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @mads for your answer and sorry for the delay cause of the holidays. I understood your answer as far as that now both files are processed by `xsl:copy-of` one after the other and a single output is created. But I still do not understand how I can use the `origin` attribute with `doc1 / doc2` (this should not be the filename). Sorry if my question was not clearly expressed.

Comment: whoops, looks like I glossed over that important detail in the output! I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your fast reply. The origin-string must be a separate string. It has nothing in common with the filename and is not derived from it. This is my main problem. The extracted structures should be enriched with a string defined by myself and this string (e.g. doc1/doc2) should be hard coded. Sorry again if I did not communicate clearly. And XSLT2.0 is completely sufficient.

Comment: Same concept applies. You could add another param for your `@origin` value and either hard-code or derive from the filename.

Comment: I have updated with examples of how to snag the numeric value from the filenames.